# jquery скролл приближение, затем движение

Tags: jquery, css

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header .mega {
  content: " ";
  background-image: url('http://cdn.demo.fabthemes.com/kansas/files/2012/08/wallpaper-722590cp.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
header .baloon1 {
  position: absolute;
}
header .baloon1 img {
  width: 130px;
}
header .baloon2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 10%;
}
header .baloon2 img {
  width: 130px;
}
header .baloon3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 30%;
}
header .baloon3 img {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <header>
            <div class="mega"></div>
            <div class="baloon1"><img src="img/baloon1.png">1</div>
            <div class="baloon2"><img src="img/baloon2.png">2</div>
            <div class="baloon3"><img src="img/baloon3.png">3</div>
        </header>
        <section>
        Hello World
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть картинка на всю ширину и высоту экрана. В ней объекты (в данном примере влепил цифры). При скроле вниз объекты увеличиваются и движутся вверх, затем появляется надпись посередине, и как только она на 100% появится, фоновая картинка медленно становится черной и теперь можно скролить вниз (в данном примере все просто скролится вниз). Как это сделать? Мне не нужен готовый пример, просто дайте направление с чего начать, как примерно это реализовать?